# Keras: load image in generator vs load image outside of generator

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, generator

in the following script I want to train a CNN with mnist data.
The data is in the dataset_dir and all images are .png. The labels are the folders of the images.
Now I want to train the CNN with a generator, which gets the imagepaths and the labels.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2, numpy as np
import random, os, glob, time
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

dataset_dir = '/home/viktor/PycharmProjects/Datasets/mnist_png/training/**/*.png' #lies alle bilder ein, egal ob train oder test set, wir splitten spaeter
NUM_CLASSES = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 128
NUM_EPOCHS = 1

def paths_and_labels(dataset_dir):
    # dataset_dir = '/home/viktor/PycharmProjects/Datasets/mnist_png/training/**/*.png' # dataset_dir soll so aussehen, die zwei ** sind die klassennamen, ordner** ist also ordner_auto, ordner_person,...
    paths = glob.glob(dataset_dir)
    labels = []
    labels.append([os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path)) for path in paths])
    labels = labels[0] #labels als string

    class_names = list(set(labels)) # welche klassen gibt es, string
    labels_classes = np.zeros([len(labels)], dtype=int)
    for i, class_name in enumerate(class_names):
        class_index = [j for j, x in enumerate(labels) if x == class_name]
        labels_classes[class_index] = i # labels als int, um die klasse als string zu bekommen, mach = class_names[labels_class[nr]]

    paths_and_labels_classes = list(zip(paths, labels_classes))
    random.shuffle(paths_and_labels_classes)
    paths, labels_classes = zip(*paths_and_labels_classes)

    train_paths = paths[0:int(0.6 * len(paths))]
    train_labels = labels_classes[0:int(0.6 * len(labels_classes))]

    test_paths = paths[int(0.8 * len(paths)):]
    test_labels = labels_classes[int(0.8 * len(labels_classes)):]

    val_paths = paths[int(0.6 * len(paths)):int(0.8 * len(paths))]
    val_labels = labels_classes[int(0.6 * len(paths)):int(0.8 * len(paths))]

    return train_paths, train_labels, test_paths, test_labels, val_paths, val_labels, class_names

def generator(image_paths, labels, batch_size):
    batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, 28, 28, 1)) #oder 224,224,3
    batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size, NUM_CLASSES))
    while True:
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # choose random index of one image in image_paths
            index = np.random.choice(len(image_paths), 1, replace=False)[0]
            im = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image_paths[index],0), (28, 28)).astype(np.float32)
            im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=2) # weil es ein CHANNEL ist, spaeter muss das glaube ich weg
            batch_features[i] = im
            batch_labels[i][labels[index]] = 1
        batch_features = batch_features.astype('float32')
        batch_features /= 255
        yield (batch_features, batch_labels)

train_paths, train_labels, test_paths, test_labels, val_paths, val_labels, c_names = paths_and_labels(dataset_dir)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
#my_callback = [keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/home/viktor/PycharmProjects/CNN_Object_Classification/logs2', histogram_freq=0, batch_size=32, write_graph=True, write_grads=False, write_images=False, embeddings_freq=0, embeddings_layer_names=None, embeddings_metadata=None)]
start_time = time.clock()
model.fit_generator(generator=generator(train_paths, train_labels, BATCH_SIZE), steps_per_epoch=int(len(train_paths)/BATCH_SIZE), epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)#,callbacks=my_callback)
elapsed_time = time.clock() - start_time
print('elapsed time: ', elapsed_time)
```

The results are not good

```
  1/281 [..............................] - ETA: 493s - loss: 16.0029 - acc: 0.1250
  2/281 [..............................] - ETA: 255s - loss: 15.9644 - acc: 0.0820
  3/281 [..............................] - ETA: 175s - loss: 39.3005 - acc: 0.0729
  4/281 [..............................] - ETA: 135s - loss: 49.8761 - acc: 0.0742
  5/281 [..............................] - ETA: 113s - loss: 55.0494 - acc: 0.0703

277/281 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 25.6649 - acc: 0.0346
278/281 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 25.6554 - acc: 0.0345
279/281 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 25.6460 - acc: 0.0343
280/281 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 25.6367 - acc: 0.0342
281/281 [==============================] - 22s - loss: 25.6274 - acc: 0.0341
elapsed time:  37.915506
```

If I try the same thing, but loading all images before giving them to the generator (and not just giving the paths), then its much better.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2, numpy as np
import random, os, glob, time
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

dataset_dir = '/home/viktor/PycharmProjects/Datasets/mnist_png/training/**/*.png' #lies alle bilder ein, egal ob train oder test set, wir splitten spaeter
NUM_CLASSES = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 128
NUM_EPOCHS = 1

def paths_and_labels(dataset_dir):
    # dataset_dir = '/home/viktor/PycharmProjects/Datasets/mnist_png/training/**/*.png' # dataset_dir soll so aussehen, die zwei ** sind die klassennamen, ordner** ist also ordner_auto, ordner_person,...
    paths = glob.glob(dataset_dir)
    labels = []
    labels.append([os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path)) for path in paths])
    labels = labels[0] #labels als string

    class_names = list(set(labels)) # welche klassen gibt es, string
    labels_classes = np.zeros([len(labels)], dtype=int)
    for i, class_name in enumerate(class_names):
        class_index = [j for j, x in enumerate(labels) if x == class_name]
        labels_classes[class_index] = i # labels als int, um die klasse als string zu bekommen, mach = class_names[labels_class[nr]]

    paths_and_labels_classes = list(zip(paths, labels_classes))
    random.shuffle(paths_and_labels_classes)
    paths, labels_classes = zip(*paths_and_labels_classes)

    train_paths = paths[0:int(0.6 * len(paths))]
    train_labels = labels_classes[0:int(0.6 * len(labels_classes))]

    test_paths = paths[int(0.8 * len(paths)):]
    test_labels = labels_classes[int(0.8 * len(labels_classes)):]

    val_paths = paths[int(0.6 * len(paths)):int(0.8 * len(paths))]
    val_labels = labels_classes[int(0.6 * len(paths)):int(0.8 * len(paths))]

    train_images = np.zeros((len(train_paths), 28, 28, 1))  # oder 224,224,3
    train_labels_bin = np.zeros((len(train_paths), NUM_CLASSES))

    for i in range(len(train_paths)):
        im = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(train_paths[i], 0), (28, 28)).astype(np.float32)
        im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=2)  # weil es ein CHANNEL ist, spaeter muss das glaube ich weg
        train_images[i] = im
        train_labels_bin[i][train_labels[i]] = 1
    train_images = train_images.astype('float32')
    train_images /= 255

    return train_images, train_labels_bin

def generator(images, labels, batch_size):
    batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, 28, 28, 1),np.float32) #oder 224,224,3
    batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size, NUM_CLASSES))
    while True:
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # choose random index of one image in image_paths
            index = np.random.choice(len(images), 1, replace=False)[0]
            batch_features[i] = images[index]
            batch_labels[i] = labels[index]
        yield (batch_features, batch_labels)

train_images, train_labels_bin = paths_and_labels(dataset_dir)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
#my_callback = [keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/home/viktor/PycharmProjects/CNN_Object_Classification/logs2', histogram_freq=0, batch_size=32, write_graph=True, write_grads=False, write_images=False, embeddings_freq=0, embeddings_layer_names=None, embeddings_metadata=None)]
start_time = time.clock()
model.fit_generator(generator=generator(train_images, train_labels_bin, BATCH_SIZE), steps_per_epoch=int(len(train_images)/BATCH_SIZE), epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)#,callbacks=my_callback)
elapsed_time = time.clock() - start_time
print('elapsed time: ', elapsed_time)
```

The results:

```
  1/281 [..............................] - ETA: 461s - loss: 2.3143 - acc: 0.0859
  2/281 [..............................] - ETA: 238s - loss: 2.3017 - acc: 0.1133
  3/281 [..............................] - ETA: 164s - loss: 2.2830 - acc: 0.1536
  4/281 [..............................] - ETA: 128s - loss: 2.2632 - acc: 0.1953
  5/281 [..............................] - ETA: 106s - loss: 2.2439 - acc: 0.2219

277/281 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4778 - acc: 0.8619
278/281 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4766 - acc: 0.8623
279/281 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4759 - acc: 0.8626
280/281 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4747 - acc: 0.8629
281/281 [==============================] - 23s - loss: 0.4735 - acc: 0.8632
elapsed time:  37.089643
```

I already checked if the output of the generator is the same. And it is.
So my question is, why is the loss so bad with the first script? Everything is the same. The only difference is, that in the first script I load the data IN the generator function.
And in the second Script I load the data outside of the generator function.

Answer (score 1):

I found my Mistake

the right generator fkt should be:

```
def generator(image_paths, labels, batch_size):

    while True:
        batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, 28, 28, 1))  # oder 224,224,3
        batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size, NUM_CLASSES))
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # choose random index of one image in image_paths
            index = np.random.choice(len(image_paths), 1, replace=False)[0]
            im = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image_paths[index],0), (28, 28)).astype(np.float32)
            im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=2) # weil es ein CHANNEL ist, spaeter muss das glaube ich weg
            batch_features[i] = im
            batch_labels[i][labels[index]] = 1
        batch_features = batch_features.astype('float32')
        batch_features /= 255
        yield (batch_features, batch_labels)
```